# Asus laptop screen turns off when unplugged - new battery

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I have a Asus R554L laptop.  The battery was just about dead so I replaced it with a new one.  With the new battery, I can see it charging and I it is working.  But as soon as I unplug the power cord, my screen will immediately turn off and go black.  The computer does not turn off and the keyboard still works while unplugged.  When I plug the power cord back in, the screen comes back on.  Computer doesn't turn off while unplugged and battery doesn't lose much battery power, but I can't get the screen to turn on.  I've checked the battery settings and even tried to set the screen to never turn off on battery.  Any ideas?  This is Windows 10.  And the problem only started when I replaced the battery. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right battery?

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that you have the wrong battery or a bad battery.

Comment: It seems like something wrong with your battery. Can you sure that the new battery you replaced works properly? I suggest you to change a battery. If there is no issue in battery, it may be something wrong with the power of this laptop.

Comment: Are you sure the battery is the correct type for your laptop?
Is it an official asus battery? Usually, aftermarket parts are fine, but if it's not working, it maybe the manufacturers fault. It could also be that your laptop detects that it's a 3rd party battery and disables it.

You can remove your hard drive completely and the battery should still charge, Windows isn't involved.